# PHP cant connect to postgreSQL in Centos 7 Selinux

Tags: php, postgresql, centos7, selinux

After migration to a new VPS and trying website on new server(Centos 7), Selinux somehow prevents http from accessing Postgresql:

> pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not
>   connect to server: Permission denied Is the server running on host
>   "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 6432

and yes my postgresql in on port 6432 because of pgbouncer that we use to reduce server load. I googled around and find out it's because of Selinux so I used selinux commands to allow httpd connection to db `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db on` and it works as in when I look in Selinux config with `sestatus -b` it's turned `ON` but the problem still exists...

> pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not
>   connect to server: Permission denied Is the server running on host
>   "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 6432

Funny thing is I know it's because of Selinux cause when I use `setenforce 0` It works and connect to postgresql without any problem.
what should I do?

Comment: I believe You could do: `semanage port -a -t postgressql_port_t -p tcp 6432`

Comment: `ValueError: Type postgressql_port_t is invalid, must be a port type`

Comment: try `unreserved_port_t`, sorry last time I touched selinux was loong time ago.

Comment: no, I think problem is with `postgressql_port_t` typo it should be `postgresql_port_t` and I tested it. It works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution with help of a [Bogdan Kuštan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4381265/bogdan-ku%C5%A1tan). It because Selinux accepts 5432 as Postgresql port and does not work with other ports. You can check acceptable ports to Selinux labeld port with `semanage port -l` command.
You can add ports to labeled ports with "semanage port -a" command with some other parameters and in my case:

```
semanage port -a -t postgresql_port_t -p tcp 6432
```